# Suppose $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $A \subseteq A'$. Prove that there is a function $g:A' \rightarrow B$ such that $f \subseteq g$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Problem: Suppose $f:A \rightarrow B$, $B \neq \varnothing$, and $A \subseteq A'$. Prove that there is a function $g:A' \rightarrow B$ such that $f \subseteq g$.

Here's my attempt, although I'm not confident in it:

We define $h$ as a function from $A’\setminus A$ to $B$.

Then, we define function $g$ as follows:
$$
g=\{(a, b) \in A' \times B | (a, b)\in f \lor (a,b)\in h\}
$$
Now, let’s verify that $f \subseteq g$.

Let $(x, y)\in f$. Then by the definition of $g$, $(x, y)\in g$.

Comment: This works, but just be careful that you are explicit when you write up your homework.  For example, you want to prove that g is a function (even though it's pretty obvious that it is).  The better you show you understand the ideas behind your proof, the better you will understand them.

Comment: The first sentence, "We define $h$ as $\dots$", needs justification. How do you know there is such an $h$? (This is where the hypothesis $B\neq\varnothing$ is needed.)